# How to cheat typing test using JavaScript to type the letters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to come up with a solution to press keys virtually for a typing test. What I want is to get the text and store individual letters in an array and then press all keys with some delay in between each presses.

This is the HTML of the text layout. Imagine it has the word `hello`.

```html
<div class="digit-container">
    <div>
        <span>h</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="digit-container">
    <div>
        <span>e</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="digit-container">
    <div>
        <span>l</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="digit-container">
    <div>
        <span>l</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="digit-container">
    <div>
        <span>o</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript code I have come up with. I have managed to store these letters in an array.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".digit-container > div > span");
const chars = Array.from(elements).map((item) => item.textContent);

const delay = 1000;

let i = 0;

const pressKey = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const char = chars[i];

    const event = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {
      key: char
    });

    document.body.dispatchEvent(event);

    if (i !== chars.length - 1) {
      i++;
      pressKey();
    }
  }, delay);
};

pressKey();

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  console.log(e.key);
});
```

However this only show the `hello` word in the console. Now I would like JavaScript to send keypresses for this array of letters { "h", "e", "l", "l", "o" }. Basically when I'm pasting this code and press enter in the console, I would like JavaScript to press "Hello" with a milliseconds of delay in between keystrokes. So I can complete the typing test. How can I get JavaScript into press keys?

Comment: Where exactly are you attempting to enter the word hello? there is no form element in you HTML to take these values.

Comment: I just want to type it. It doesn't have a box to text to go. Just have to press `hello` and the test completes.

Comment: You need to find the event listener for the site you're trying to hack and hook into that

Comment: @freedomn-m can you explain a little further?

Comment: If I create a page with an `input` and listen for `keyup` on that input, then your code sends `keyup` to `document` - my event handler won't fire.  Equally, if I listen for `keydown` and you send `keyup`, I won't get your event - regardless of input/focus - if you're sending the wrong event, I won't get it.  So you need to hack your site a little further to determine how it's handling input.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks I got. I can view the event listers from the chrome dev tools right?

Answer (score 1):

You got downvoted a lot because, in general, people dislike questions about *how to hack*... But I checked if it was ok to answer your question and found that [if the question focusses on the technical aspect and includes a reasonnable effort, it is okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295450/2159528).

I have to admit I was looking for a fullproof reason to close your question (!)... But since you are very close to find the solution anyway, here is how to do it AND how to prevent it (for a website owner).

---

So as mentionned in comments, you need to dispatch the events to the right element where the user should type... So, not to the `document.body`.

But about which events to dispatch, that is quite simple. When typing in an input, the events fired are (in order): `keydown`, `keypress`, `input` and `keyup`. See below:

```js
let targetInput = document.querySelector("#test");
let targetEvents = ["blur", "focus", "input", "keydown", "keyup", "keypress", "select"];

targetEvents.forEach(function (evt) {
  targetInput.addEventListener(evt, (event) => {
    console.log(`${event.type}`)
    setTimeout(()=>console.clear(),1600)
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="txt" id="test">
```

So if you want to *almost perfectly* simulate a user keyboard action, my suggestion is to simulate those four... And you also have to append the key value to the input's value.

## How to prevent this hack method

That said... I also am one of those who quite dislike to encourage hacking. So I am also providing the way to know if the keyboard action was simulated via JS or not. A *real keyboard action* has the `istrusted` property setted tro `true`. The browser provides that information and it cannot be overrided via JS. So if you are an owner of a website which need to test *real user* actions, you need to check the `isTrusted` property of events.

```js
let targetInput = document.querySelector("#test");
let targetEvents = ["keydown", "keypress", "input", "keyup"];

targetEvents.forEach(function (evt) {
  targetInput.addEventListener(evt, (event) => {
    console.log(`${(event.isTrusted)?"Real user ":"JavaScript"} - ${event.type}: ${event.key}`)
    if(event.isTrusted){
      setTimeout(()=>console.clear(),3000)
    }
  });
})

let chars = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"];

let i = 0;
const pressKey = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const char = chars[i];

    // Dispatch all the events
    targetEvents.forEach(function (evt) {
      let event = new KeyboardEvent(evt, {
        key: char,
        isTrusted: true  // Useless attempt overriding the isTrusted property
      });
      targetInput.dispatchEvent(event);
      
    });
    
    // Add the letter to the input value
    targetInput.value += char;

    if (i !== chars.length - 1) {
      i++;
      pressKey();
    }
  }, 150);
};

pressKey();
```

```html
<input type="txt" id="test">
```